# Is it possible define param type from class variable with phpdoc in PHP

Tags: php, phpdoc

now I have this:

```
class UserProvider
{
    protected string $className = User::class;

    /**
     * @param User $entity
     */
    public function getData($entity): array
    {
        $data['name'] = $entity->getName();

        return $data;
    }
}
```

but I am looking  for something like this:

```
class UserProvider
{
    protected string $className = User::class;

    /**
     * @param [UserProvider->className] $entity
     */
    public function getData($entity): array
    {
        $data['name'] = $entity->getName();

        return $data;
    }
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't define the type of the actual parameter - `getData(string $entity): array`?

Comment: @NigelRen updated my question

Comment: This looks like it's about being able to use Generics (https://stitcher.io/blog/generics-in-php-1)

Comment: What are you trying to do? Only type references I know, are `self` and `static`.